# Grails build test war fails in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, grails, groovy

I have a grails project I am currently developing in a Windows7 environment. I just set up a Ubuntu 14.xx desktop. Groovy is same version for both, 2.3.3, Java is the same version, 1.6.0_45, and Grails is the same version, 2.3.7. I can run "grails test war" in the Windows environment and the war is built no errors. I have everything in Bitbucket. I check out the code to the ubuntu box, run "grails test war" and get this:

Packaging Grails application.....
| Error log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
| Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/logs/.log (No such file or directory)

Why will this give errors fora build?

Doesn't make much sense to me.

Anyone know how to prevent the errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: regular users are not allowed to write `/var/logs/.log`.  does your log4j in `Config` contains windows-isms?

Comment: I am sure you have another error, I was getting same error as you posted but that does not prevent you from building a war , you must still get the war file. But if your question , why I am getting this error? I can post you an answer.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was not building the war completely, but it is. And it does run. But if you can answer the question I would love to understand why.